# I left chicken stock out overnight

Tags: food-safety, stock

I am making a chicken thigh recipe to be grilled later in the week.

Yesterday late afternoon I boiled the thighs in salty-peppered-bay leafy water for 30 mins.

I took the chicken out and it's now marinading in the fridge.

I meant to put the stock away (I really did).

Can it be used, or is it a biohazard at this point?